# UWP: The component cannot be found (Exception from HRESULT: 0x88982F50)

Tags: c#, uwp

I sometimes get an error when i try to take a picture within my uwp app. 
This error is very hard to reproduce and happend a few min ago on desktop platform. I used a hovercam to retrieve the imagebuffer.

```
    public async Task<IBuffer> TakePhotoAsync()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("taking picture...");

        using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            try
            {
                await mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), stream);
                Debug.WriteLine("captured to stream");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ExceptionHandler.Instance.HandleException(e);
            }

            //rotate img
            return await GetRotatedIBuffer(stream);

        }
    }

    public async Task<IBuffer> GetRotatedIBuffer(IRandomAccessStream stream)
    {
        //rotate img
        using (var imageStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            BitmapDecoder dec = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
            BitmapEncoder enc = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(stream, dec);

            BitmapRotation rotation = BitmapRotation.None;
            switch (App.settings.DefaultCamera.Rotation)
            {
                case VideoRotation.Clockwise180Degrees:
                    rotation = BitmapRotation.Clockwise180Degrees;
                    break;
                case VideoRotation.Clockwise270Degrees:
                    rotation = BitmapRotation.Clockwise270Degrees;
                    break;
                case VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees:
                    rotation = BitmapRotation.Clockwise90Degrees;
                    break;
            }

            enc.BitmapTransform.Rotation = rotation;
            await enc.FlushAsync();

            try
            {
                await RandomAccessStream.CopyAsync(stream,imageStream);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionHandler.Instance.HandleException(ex);
            }

            return await StreamHelpers.StreamToIBuffer(imageStream);
        }
    }
```

output:

```
taking picture...
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in               mscorlib.ni.dll
WinRT information: Started
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0xC00D36B2): The request is not valid in current state
Started
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at KNFB_Reader_Windows10.KNFBCamera.<TakePhotoAsync>d__25.MoveNext()
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in mscorlib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in mscorlib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in mscorlib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in mscorlib.ni.dll

The component cannot be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x88982F50)
```

Comment: Are you sure, that CapturePhotoToStreamAsync is performed in the UIThread?

Comment: Yeah, it is called from a button event handler

Comment: @PrisonMike It's hard to say where the issue is. Please try to run the official [Basic camera app sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/c219fea5c127b83a1064f57bb92a14e06f539ef8/Samples/CameraStarterKit) to see if you still face this issue. If not, you might need to provide a simple reproducible code sample to me, I'll help you diagnose it.