# Exception when trying to rotate an image taken by a camera

Tags: c#, encoding, camera, stream, uwp

My app analytics are showing this exception on desktops and phones:

STOWED_EXCEPTION_System.Exception_88982f50_KNFB-Reader_Windows10.dll!$0_MyApp_Windows10::MyCamera::_GetRotatedIBuffer_d__27.MoveNext

Can someone please explain to me what's wrong with the code below?

Here's the stacktrace:

[image]

```
public async Task<IBuffer> TakePhotoAsync()
{
        Debug.WriteLine("taking picture...");

        using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            try
            {
                await mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), stream);
                Debug.WriteLine("captured to stream");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ExceptionHandler.Instance.HandleException(e);
            }

            //rotate img
            return await GetRotatedIBuffer(stream);
        }
}

public async Task<IBuffer> GetRotatedIBuffer(IRandomAccessStream stream)
{
        //rotate img
        using (var imageStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            BitmapDecoder dec = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
            BitmapEncoder enc = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(imageStream, dec);

            BitmapRotation rotation = BitmapRotation.None;
            switch (KNFBSettings.Instance.DefaultCamera.Rotation)
            {
                case VideoRotation.Clockwise180Degrees:
                    rotation = BitmapRotation.Clockwise180Degrees;
                    break;
                case VideoRotation.Clockwise270Degrees:
                    rotation = BitmapRotation.Clockwise270Degrees;
                    break;
                case VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees:
                    rotation = BitmapRotation.Clockwise90Degrees;
                    break;
            }

            enc.BitmapTransform.Rotation = rotation;
            await enc.FlushAsync();

            return await StreamHelpers.StreamToIBuffer(imageStream);
        }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UWP: The component cannot be found (Exception from HRESULT: 0x88982F50)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41826340/uwp-the-component-cannot-be-found-exception-from-hresult-0x88982f50)

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue. Please provide a reproducible code sample. Thanks.

Comment: That's the problem, i can't reproduce it either